# Getting results of a ping in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm using powershell to ping an IP address and I would like to be able to send an email based on that response. So for example if I ping my IP address and it's working then I want to send an email that says it's on, but if I ping the IP address and I get `Request Timed Out` then I don't send an email.

My code

```
$Username = "username";
$Password = "password";

ping ip_address

function Send-ToEmail([string]$email){

    $message = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage;
    $message.From = "from@test.com";
    $message.To.Add($email);
    $message.Subject = "subject text here...";
    $message.Body = "body text here...";

    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.mailtrap.io", "2525");
    $smtp.EnableSSL = $false;
    $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
    $smtp.send($message);
    write-host "Mail Sent" ; 
 }

Send-ToEmail  -email "reciever@test.com";
```

Comment: You may use `Test-Connection` instead of `ping`. Please read the complete help including the examples to learn how to use it.

Comment: I will look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The proper pure Powershell way would be something like this

```
if (Test-Connection -ComputerName 'IPAddress' -Count 1 -Quiet) {
    'Send email'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to send an email if I get a response back from my IP address.

I added this code to my file.

```
$ping = ping ip_address -n 1 | Where-Object {$_ -match "Reply" -or $_ -match "Request timed out" -or $_ -match "Destination host unreachable"} 


If($ping -match "Reply")
{
    Send-ToEmail  -email "reciever@test.com" -content "The computer is on";    
}
```

Comment: Instead of using ping (which requires parsing) I advise you to use Test-Connection

Comment: I don't think your code will work because it will send email even when the machine is not pingable. Consider this output: `Reply from 192.168.1.222: Destination host unreachable.`. Your code looks for a match on `Reply`.